# Posting JSON via JQuery to Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm having a surprisingly tough time getting json to post from javascript to a rails backed web service.

Here is the jquery code;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jsonPost = { 
      "email":"dummy@dummy.com",
      "token":"63uO6eEfLVBFpnZswzI",
      "content": "testcontent",
      "notification_type": "2",
      "name":"testname",
}
  function callback(data){alert(data)};

jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/create.json',
        data: jsonPost,
        success: callback,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: false
      });


</script>
```

On the rails side:

```
def api_create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {
      email = params[:email]
      token = params[:token]
      auto_action = params[:auto_action]
```

The rails side does recognize the request as JSON, but I see no data in the request when debugging in rails.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need to convert your JSON into a string, if you're doing the opposite in rails?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/create.json',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonPost),
    success: callback,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false
  });
```

Comment: I tried this before, and now again with your suggestion.  I see nothing in the request inside of rails.  Perhaps someone could tell me what I should look for in the request?  Here is what I see for the rails request object in the debugger: http://cl.ly/Htvn

Comment: I'm still looking into a similar issue myself, but know you don't need to stringify. See the very clear video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nL7X1UMWsc.